# How to translate the route system in django 1 to django 2,3?

Tags: python, django

In tutorial the author used an old version of `urls.py` in urlpatterns and I cannot translate

```
url(r'^image/(?P<width>[0-9]+)x(?P<height>[0-9]+)/$')
```

this into

```
path()
```

Thanks a lot

I would like to resolve this issue

Comment: `re_path` i think is what you would use for that pattern

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#re-path):

```py
re_path(r'^image/(?P<width>[0-9]+)x(?P<height>[0-9]+)/$')
```

Alternatively, translate this into a path. This is your view:

```py
def something(request, width, height): ...
```

and in `urls.py`:

```py
path("image/<int:width>x<int:height>/", views.something)
```

Comment: thanks, but I would like to get an answer as "path" no "re_path"